# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string

Tags: java, swing

I am getting difficulty in adding card layout.I am sharing my code here.

```
package LoginUser;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


import DBconnection.SelectTable;
import DBconnection.TestConnection;
import GUITTG.Branch;
import GUITTG.TTGFrame;

import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class LoginForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    char ch;
    //Container con1;
  JPanel jpanelMainMain,jpanelMain,jpanelMainC;
  JPanel jpanelMainC1,jpanelMainC2,jpanelMainC3;
  JPanle jpanelMainC4,jpanelMainC5,jpanelMainC6;
  CardLayout cardLayout;

  JButton login,register;
  JLabel id,pass;
  JTextField idtxt;
  Font font;
  JPasswordField pw;
  RegisterForm rf;
  TestConnection tb;
  SelectTable stble;
  Statement st;
  Connection con;
  ResultSet rs;
  TTGFrame ttg;
  Container con1;
  public LoginForm()
  {

UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ClassLoader",       this.getClass().getClassLoader());
      this.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
      setBackground(new Color(0 ,0 ,0));


       con1=getContentPane();
        cardLayout=new CardLayout();
        jpanelMainMain=new JPanel(cardLayout);

      font=new Font("title",Font.PLAIN,20);

      id=new JLabel("Login Id:");
      id.setFont(font);
      id.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      pass=new JLabel("Password:");
      pass.setFont(font);
      pass.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

      idtxt=new JTextField();
      pw=new JPasswordField();


      login=new JButton("Login");
      register=new JButton("Register");


      jpanelMain=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMain.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0 ,0 ,0)), "Login Form", 0, 0, font, new Color(0 ,0 ,0)));
      jpanelMain.add(new JLabel() ,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    /*  jpanelMainC1=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC1.add(id);

      jpanelMainC2=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC2.add(pass);

      jpanelMainC3=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC3.add(idtxt);

      jpanelMainC4=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC4.add(pw);

      jpanelMainC5=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC5.add(login);

      jpanelMainC6=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC6.add(register);
      */

      jpanelMainC=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

      jpanelMainC.add(id);
      jpanelMainC.add(pass);
      jpanelMainC.add(idtxt);
      jpanelMainC.add(pw);
      jpanelMainC.add(login);
      jpanelMainC.add(register);

      /*jpanelMainC=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      jpanelMainC.add(jpanelMainC1);
      jpanelMainC.add(jpanelMainC2);
      jpanelMainC.add(jpanelMainC3);
      jpanelMainC.add(jpanelMainC4);
      jpanelMainC.add(jpanelMainC5);
      jpanelMainC.add(jpanelMainC6);*/
      jpanelMain.add(jpanelMainC ,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      jpanelMainC.setBackground(new Color(0,150,150));
      jpanelMainMain.setBackground(new Color(0,150,150));
     add(id);
     add(pass);
      add(idtxt);
      add(pw);
     add(login);
      add(register);


      con1.setLayout(null);
      con1.setBackground(new Color(0,150,150));

      id.setBounds(100,100,100,30);
      pass.setBounds(100,150,100,20);

      idtxt.setBounds(210,100,100,20);
      pw.setBounds(210,150,100,20);

      login.setBounds(100,200,100,20);
      register.setBounds(210,200,100,20);


      login.addActionListener(this);
      register.addActionListener(this);


    //  con1.add(jpanelMain);
      jpanelMainMain.add(jpanelMain);
      cardLayout.show(jpanelMainMain ,"LoginForm");

      tb=new TestConnection();

      idtxt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
      {
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
           {
              char c = ke.getKeyChar();
              if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||(c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
              (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) 
             {
              getToolkit().beep();
               ke.consume();
            }
           }
      });
      pw.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
      {
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
           {
              char c = ke.getKeyChar();
              if (((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||(c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
              (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) 
             {
              getToolkit().beep();
               ke.consume();
            }
           }
      });         
 }


public void setLookAndFeel(String name) 
{
    if(name == null)
      {
          return;
      }
      try
      {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(name);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
      }     

}

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
      int cnt=0;
    if(ae.getSource()==login)
    {
        try
        {
             con=tb.getConnection();
             st=tb.getStatement();
             stble=new SelectTable(st);
             stble.getConnWithTable("login_table");
             rs=stble.getResultSet();
             String i=idtxt.getText();
             String p=pw.getText();
             while(rs.next())
             {
                 if(rs.getString(1).equals(i)&&rs.getString(2).equals(p))
                     cnt=1;
             }

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        if(cnt==1)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Login Success......");
        ttg=new TTGFrame();
        ttg.setTitle("Time Table Application.TTG Frame Form");
        ttg.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Login Fail......try again?");
             idtxt.setText("");
             pw.setText("");
        }   
    }


    else
    {
        rf=new RegisterForm();
        rf.setTitle("Time Table Application.Registration Form");
        rf.setSize(1000,1000);
        rf.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);

    }

  }

  public JPanel getMyJPanel()
{
    return jpanelMain;
}

public String getMyName()
{
    return "LoginForm";
}


  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
        LoginForm l=new LoginForm();
        l.setTitle("Time Table Application.Login Form");
        l.setSize(500,500);
        l.setResizable(false);
        l.setVisible(true);

        //this.setTitle("Time-Table Application.Branch");

        //setVisible(true);

  }

}  
  class WindowUtilities 
  {

    /** Tell system to use native look and feel, as in previous
        *  releases. Metal (Java) LAF is the default otherwise.
        */

    public static void setNativeLookAndFeel() 
        {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
        }
        }

        public static void setJavaLookAndFeel() 
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error setting Java LAF: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void setMotifLookAndFeel() 
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error setting Motif LAF: " + e);
        }
    }

    /** A simplified way to see a JPanel or other Container.
    *  Pops up a JFrame with specified Container as the content pane.
    */

    public static JFrame openInJFrame(Container content, int width, int height, String title, Color bgColor) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setBackground(bgColor);
        content.setBackground(bgColor);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return(frame);
    }

    /** Uses Color.white as the background color. */

    public static JFrame openInJFrame(Container content, int width, int height, String title) 
    {
        return(openInJFrame(content, width, height, title, Color.white));
    }

    /** Uses Color.white as the background color, and the
    *  name of the Container's class as the JFrame title.
    */

    public static JFrame openInJFrame(Container content, int width, int height) 
    {
        return(openInJFrame(content, width, height, content.getClass().getName(), Color.white));
    }
  }
```

I am getting following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to

layout: constraint must be a string

```
at java.awt.CardLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at LoginUser.LoginForm.<init>(LoginForm.java:158)
at LoginUser.LoginForm.main(LoginForm.java:277)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to 
>   layout: constraint must be a string

```
  jpanelMainMain.add(jpanelMain);
```

Message seems straight forward to me. You didn't specify a String constraint when you added a component to the panel using a CardLayout.

```
  cardLayout.show(jpanelMainMain ,"LoginForm");
```

How does the CardLayout know which panel is the "LoginForm" if you don't specify the constraint when you add the panel to the CardLayout?

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working examples that shows you how to specify the constraint when you add a panel to the CardLayout. It also shows how to swap panels by specify a constraint.